# Angular: Delete item - delete from array or reload from database

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I have an array of Objects which gets displayed on the Ui.

When an entry get's deleted / modifyed / added, there happens an api-call to store / modify / delete the data on the database. In case I get a 200 status response, I'd like to refresh the list on the Ui.

```
public deleteObject { 
  this.http.delete(...)
    .subscribe( () => {

      // here the getter method would get called, to get all objects

    }, (error: ErrorModel) => {
      this.errorHandler.handle(error);
  });
}
```

Which way is most common / performant to refresh the list of objects?

- Call this.getAllObject() to make new get-request?
- Return list of objects with the post / put / delete to avoid second server call?
- Modify / delete / add row to existing array, to prevent sending hole list again through the internet?
- Other way?

Comment: third option seems better & if delete is not successful then again show the element

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler for you to remove the item from the local array.

```
delete(item).subscribe(response => {
  const index = find index of the current item (either by keeping a reference while deleting, or looping through the array to find it)
  this.myArray = this.myArray.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends ... If you have a lot of data to process in the backend and this slows down the performance, you can use the modified array, otherwise make a new request to the server.